# Reducing the height so that the section does not take up so much of the screen

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make this section not so big when scrolling I feel it takes too much of the screen. Does anyone have any ideas to make it not so long? Thanks in advance to any one who helps.

```css
.content-sm {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container {
    width: 1170px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px)
.container {
    width: 970px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.container {
    width: 750px;
}
.container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
* {
    border-radius: 0;
}


/*Business Posts Section
------------------------------------*/
.business-post-section {
  position: relative;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}


/*Business Posts Links/Buttons
------------------------------------*/
.business-post-link {
 padding-top: 25px;
 text-align: center;
}

.business-post-link i {
 color: #fff;
 width: 90px;
 height: 90px;
 padding: 30px;
 font-size: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 background: #00539c;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.business-post-link i:after {
 top: -8px;
 left: -8px;
 right: -8px;
 bottom: -8px;
 content: " ";
 position: absolute;
 border: 1px solid #dedede;
 border-radius: 50% !important;
}

.business-post-link:hover i,
.business-post-link:hover i:after {
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.business-post-link:hover i {
 background: #db9e33;
}

.business-post-link:hover i:after {
 border-color: #db9e33;
}

.rounded-x {
    border-radius: 50% !important;
}

.business-post-title {
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 24px;
 color: #555;
}
  

@media (min-width: 768px)
.col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
} 
@media (min-width: 768px)
.col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9 {
    float: left;
} 
.col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-line-icons/2.4.1/css/simple-line-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <!--=== Business Block ===-->
  <div class="business-post-section">
  <div class="container content-sm">
   <div class="row ">
    <a href="http://www.test.com">
    <div class="col-sm-4 business-post-link">
     <i class="rounded-x icon-drawer"></i>
     <h2 class="business-post-title">Tax Collection Solutions</h2>
    </div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.test.com">
    <div class="col-sm-4 business-post-link">
     <i class="rounded-x icon-flag"></i>
     <h2 class="business-post-title">Auction Solutions</h2>
    </div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.test.com">
    <div class="col-sm-4 business-post-link">
     <i class="rounded-x icon-wallet"></i>
     <h2 class="business-post-title">Payment Solutions</h2>
    </div>
    </a>
   </div><!--/row-->
  </div><!--/container-->
  </div>
  
  <!--=== Contact Us Block ===-->
  <div class="business-post-section">
  <div class="container content-sm">
   <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <a href="http://www.test.com">
    <div class="col-sm-4 business-post-link">
     <i class="rounded-x icon-screen-desktop"></i>
     <h2 class="business-post-title">Request a Demo</h2>
    </div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.test.com">
    <div class="col-sm-4 business-post-link">
     <i class="rounded-x icon-call-in"></i>
     <h2 class="business-post-title">Contact Us</h2>
    </div>
    </a>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
   </div><!--/row-->
  </div><!--/container-->
  </div>
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd adjust `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` for `.content-sm` to `1rem` as follows:

```css
.content-sm {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) .container {
  width: 1170px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) .container {
  width: 970px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) .container {
  width: 750px;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

* {
  border-radius: 0;
}


/*Business Posts Section
------------------------------------*/

.business-post-section {
  position: relative;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}


/*Business Posts Links/Buttons
------------------------------------*/

.business-post-link {
  padding-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.business-post-link i {
  color: #fff;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background: #00539c;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.business-post-link i:after {
  top: -8px;
  left: -8px;
  right: -8px;
  bottom: -8px;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
}

.business-post-link:hover i,
.business-post-link:hover i:after {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.business-post-link:hover i {
  background: #db9e33;
}

.business-post-link:hover i:after {
  border-color: #db9e33;
}

.rounded-x {
  border-radius: 50% !important;
}

.business-post-title {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #555;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) .col-sm-4 {
  width: 33.33333333%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) .col-sm-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) .col-sm-1,
.col-sm-10,
.col-sm-11,
.col-sm-12,
.col-sm-2,
.col-sm-3,
.col-sm-4,
.col-sm-5,
.col-sm-6,
.col-sm-7,
.col-sm-8,
.col-sm-9 {
  float: left;
}

.col-lg-1,
.col-lg-10,
.col-lg-11,
.col-lg-12,
.col-lg-2,
.col-lg-3,
.col-lg-4,
.col-lg-5,
.col-lg-6,
.col-lg-7,
.col-lg-8,
.col-lg-9,
.col-md-1,
.col-md-10,
.col-md-11,
.col-md-12,
.col-md-2,
.col-md-3,
.col-md-4,
.col-md-5,
.col-md-6,
.col-md-7,
.col-md-8,
.col-md-9,
.col-sm-1,
.col-sm-10,
.col-sm-11,
.col-sm-12,
.col-sm-2,
.col-sm-3,
.col-sm-4,
.col-sm-5,
.col-sm-6,
.col-sm-7,
.col-sm-8,
.col-sm-9,
.col-xs-1,
.col-xs-10,
.col-xs-11,
.col-xs-12,
.col-xs-2,
.col-xs-3,
.col-xs-4,
.col-xs-5,
.col-xs-6,
.col-xs-7,
.col-xs-8,
.col-xs-9 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-line-icons/2.4.1/css/simple-line-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrapper">
  <!--=== Business Block ===-->
  <div class="business-post-section">
    <div class="container content-sm">
      <div class="row ">
        <a href="http://www.test.com">
          <div class="col-sm-4 business-post-link">
            <i class="rounded-x icon-drawer"></i>
            <h2 class="business-post-title">Tax Collection Solutions</h2>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.test.com">
          <div class="col-sm-4 business-post-link">
            <i class="rounded-x icon-flag"></i>
            <h2 class="business-post-title">Auction Solutions</h2>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.test.com">
          <div class="col-sm-4 business-post-link">
            <i class="rounded-x icon-wallet"></i>
            <h2 class="business-post-title">Payment Solutions</h2>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <!--/row-->
    </div>
    <!--/container-->
  </div>

  <!--=== Contact Us Block ===-->
  <div class="business-post-section">
    <div class="container content-sm">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        <a href="http://www.test.com">
          <div class="col-sm-4 business-post-link">
            <i class="rounded-x icon-screen-desktop"></i>
            <h2 class="business-post-title">Request a Demo</h2>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.test.com">
          <div class="col-sm-4 business-post-link">
            <i class="rounded-x icon-call-in"></i>
            <h2 class="business-post-title">Contact Us</h2>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
      </div>
      <!--/row-->
    </div>
    <!--/container-->
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would probably cut the padding top/bottom in half on content-sm and then get rid of the margin between the icon and the h2 below:

```
.content-sm { padding: 30px 0; }
.business-post-link i { margin-bottom: 0; }
```

Not sure if you wanted me to re-post your whole CSS but that's where I would start, then incrementally reduce the size of the icons themselves until it fit better with the other content.